# My flag value is not returning false or true as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, flags

I'm trying to verify is a list of numbers i choose has in all elements diferent numbers. I set a flag variable true if all values in list were diferent and false otherwise. However my function is returning zero and not true or false. I know i inicialize my flag variable at zero because i needed to defined that same variable at the start of the function

i already came up with a code but my function is returning zero. My for sentence is not beeing iterated

```
v=[]

def creat_function():
    v=[int(input('digit a number\n')) for j in range(0,int(input('number of elements\n')))]
    return v
print(creat_function())

def diferences(v):
    flag=0
    for j in range(0,len(v)):
        if v[j-1]!=v[j]:
            flag=True
        else:
            flag=False
    return flag
print(diferences(v))
```

Comment: You need to get your output from `creat_function` and pass it to `diferences` @Luismaia1994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the list output which you get from `creat_function` and pass it to `diferences` function

```
def creat_function():

    v=[int(input('digit a number\n')) for j in range(0,int(input('number of elements\n')))]
    return v

def diferences(v):
    flag=0
    for j in range(0,len(v)):
        if v[j-1]!=v[j]:
            flag=True
        else:
            flag=False
    return flag

#Get list from creat_function
v = creat_function()

#Pass it to diferences
print(diferences(v))
```

Update: If you really want to use global, you can do as follows

```
v=[]

def creat_function():
    #v is global
    global v
    v=[int(input('digit a number\n')) for j in range(0,int(input('number of elements\n')))]


def diferences():
    # v is global
    global v
    flag=0
    for j in range(0,len(v)):
        if v[j-1]!=v[j]:
            flag=True
        else:
            flag=False
    return flag

#Get list from creat_function
creat_function()

#Pass it to diferences
print(diferences())
```

Output will be

```
number of elements
5
digit a number
1
digit a number
2
digit a number
3
digit a number
4
digit a number
5
True


number of elements
5
digit a number
1
digit a number
1
digit a number
2
digit a number
3
digit a number
3
False
```

Comment: i think i didnt get it xD.

Comment: I am taking the output of `creat_function` into variable `v`, then passing that variable `v` to `diferences` function @Luismaia1994

Comment: but when i did a list comprehension haven't i  already created the list. The list is a global element. In my second function in my for iteration i iterat over the vector. Why the need of passing the variable v to difernces function?

Comment: It's not global until you mention it in the `creat_function` by doing `global v`, but why do you want to do global variables, this problem can be solved without that! @Luismaia1994

Comment: Anyhow if you want to use global variable, I have added the code to do it as well @Luismaia1994

Answer (score 2):

looks like he is assuming v is global and he don't have to store return value in v.

for accessing global variables we need to use **global** keyword

```
v=[]

def creat_function():
    global v
    v=[int(input('digit a number\n')) for j in range(0,int(input('number of elements\n')))]
    return v
print(creat_function())

def diferences(v):
    flag=0
    for j in range(0,len(v)):
        if v[j-1]!=v[j]:
            flag=True
        else:
            flag=False
    return flag
print(diferences(v))
```

Comment: however if i did this without using list comprehension and appending all elements i did not have to define v as global and that i dont get it